# How to set class weights for imbalanced classes in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, weighted-data

I know that there is a possibility in Keras with the `class_weights` parameter dictionary at fitting, but I couldn't find any example. Would somebody so kind to provide one?

By the way, in this case the appropriate praxis is simply to weight up the minority class proportionally to its underrepresentation?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

If you are talking about the regular case, where your network produces only one output, then your assumption is correct. In order to force your algorithm to treat every instance of **class 1** as 50 instances of **class 0** you have to:

1. Define a dictionary with your labels and their associated weights

   ```
   class_weight = {0: 1.,
                   1: 50.,
                   2: 2.}
   ```
2. Feed the dictionary as a parameter:

   ```
   model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32, class_weight=class_weight)
   ```

EDIT:
"treat every instance of **class 1** as 50 instances of **class 0**" means that in your loss function you assign higher value to these instances.
Hence, the loss becomes a weighted average, where the weight of each sample is specified by **class_weight** and its corresponding class.

From [Keras docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/):

> **class_weight**: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only).

Comment: Also have a look at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3653 if you're working with 3D data.

Comment: For me it gives a error dic don't has shape attribute.

Comment: I believe Keras could be changing the way this works, this is for the version of August 2016. I will verify for you in a week

Comment: Does this work for one-hot-encoded labels?

Comment: @layser Does this work only for 'category_crossentropy' loss? How do you give class_weight to keras for 'sigmoid' and 'binary_crossentropy' loss?

Comment: @layser Can you explain ` to treat every instance of class 1 as 50 instances of class 0 ` ? Is it that the in training set, row corresponding to class 1 is duplicated 50 times in order to make it balanced or some other process follows?

Comment: How can we know which class is class0? Same for the class1.

Comment: How can I do that If I have NER model? 
Please check  out the quesion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69721622/named-entity-recognition-model-always-predicts-the-same-class-but-gives-accuracy

Answer (score 234):

You could simply implement the [`class_weight`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html) from `sklearn`:

1. Let's import the module first

   ```
   from sklearn.utils import class_weight
   ```
2. In order to calculate the class weight do the following

   ```
   class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                    np.unique(y_train),
                                                    y_train)
   ```
3. Thirdly and lastly add it to the model fitting

   ```
   model.fit(X_train, y_train, class_weight=class_weights)
   ```

**Attention**: I edited this post and changed the variable name from *class_weight* to *class_weight**s*** in order to not to overwrite the imported module. Adjust accordingly when copying code from the comments.

Comment: For me, `class_weight.compute_class_weight ` produces an array, I need to change it to a dict in order to work with Keras. More specifically, after step 2, use `class_weight_dict = dict(enumerate(class_weight))`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. For a three class problem in keras `y_train` is `(300096, 3)` numpy array. So the `class_weight=` line gives me TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: @Lembik I had a similar problem, where each row of y is a one-hot encoded vector of the class index. I fixed it by converting the one-hot representation to an int like this: `y_ints = [y.argmax() for y in y_train]`.

Comment: What if I'm doing multiclass labeling so that my y_true vectors have multiple 1s in them: [1 0 0 0 1 0 0] for instance, where some x has labels 0 and 4.
Even then, the total # of each of my labels is not balanced. How would I use class weights with that?

Comment: Thanks, just a small update. compute_class_weight does not work with positional arguments anymore. You'll have to specify the keyword arguments `class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(y_train), weights=y_train)`

Comment: use this:
`class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced',
                                                 classes=np.unique(train["label"]),
                                                 y=train["label"])`
And for passing into keras model.fit
`class_weight=dict(zip(np.unique(train["label"]),class_weights))`

Answer (score 39):

I use this kind of rule for `class_weight` :

```
import numpy as np
import math

# labels_dict : {ind_label: count_label}
# mu : parameter to tune 

def create_class_weight(labels_dict,mu=0.15):
    total = np.sum(list(labels_dict.values()))
    keys = labels_dict.keys()
    class_weight = dict()
    
    for key in keys:
        score = math.log(mu*total/float(labels_dict[key]))
        class_weight[key] = score if score > 1.0 else 1.0
    
    return class_weight

# random labels_dict
labels_dict = {0: 2813, 1: 78, 2: 2814, 3: 78, 4: 7914, 5: 248, 6: 7914, 7: 248}

create_class_weight(labels_dict)
```

`math.log` smooths the weights for very imbalanced classes !
This returns :

```
{0: 1.0,
 1: 3.749820767859636,
 2: 1.0,
 3: 3.749820767859636,
 4: 1.0,
 5: 2.5931008483842453,
 6: 1.0,
 7: 2.5931008483842453}
```

Comment: Why use log instead of just dividing the count of samples for a class by the total number of samples? I am assume there is something I don't understand goes into the param class_weight on model.fit_generator(...)

Comment: @startoftext That's how I did it, but I think you have it inverted.  I used `n_total_samples / n_class_samples` for each class.

Comment: In your example class 0 (has 2813 examples) and class 6 (has 7914 examples) have weight exactly 1.0. Why is that? The class 6 is few times bigger! You would want class 0 be upscaled and class 6 downscaled to bring them to the same level.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs cuz he is doing it to smooth the weights. When imbalance in classes is measured by orders of magnitude, it's not very helpful to assign weights like 100. It's gonna harm bigger class: FPs on that scarce class with high weight

Comment: If i have a imbalance as ```{0: 1300000, 1: 40, 2: 2000}``` . Is there any intuition as to how I can set the `mu` parameter here ? to handle the smoothing

Comment: @lamo [this example explains how](https://www.kaggle.com/eikedehling/exploring-class-imbalance-resampling-and-weights) they get a value of 0.14 which is close to the  "magical" 0.15 shown in this answer.

Answer (score 15):

`class_weight` is fine but as @Aalok said this won't work if you are one-hot encoding multilabeled classes. In this case, use `sample_weight`:

> `sample_weight`: optional array of the same length as x, containing
> weights to apply to the model's loss for each sample. In the case of
> temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape (samples,
> sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of
> every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify
> `sample_weight_mode="temporal"` in `compile()`.

`sample_weights` is used to **provide a weight for each training sample**. That means that you should pass a 1D array with the same number of elements as your training samples (indicating the weight for each of those samples).

`class_weights` is used to provide a **weight or bias for each output class**. This means you should pass a weight for each class that you are trying to classify.

`sample_weight` must be given a numpy array, since its shape will be evaluated.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315094/using-sample-weight-in-keras-for-sequence-labelling).

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the solution at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115. If you need more than class weighting where you want different costs for false positives and false negatives. With the new keras version now you can just override the respective loss function as given below.
Note that `weights` is a square matrix.

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import losses_utils

class WeightedCategoricalCrossentropy(keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy):

    def __init__(
        self,
        weights,
        from_logits=False,
        label_smoothing=0,
        reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,
        name='categorical_crossentropy',
    ):
        super().__init__(
            from_logits, label_smoothing, reduction, name=f"weighted_{name}"
        )
        self.weights = weights

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        weights = self.weights
        nb_cl = len(weights)
        final_mask = keras.backend.zeros_like(y_pred[:, 0])
        y_pred_max = keras.backend.max(y_pred, axis=1)
        y_pred_max = keras.backend.reshape(
            y_pred_max, (keras.backend.shape(y_pred)[0], 1))
        y_pred_max_mat = keras.backend.cast(
            keras.backend.equal(y_pred, y_pred_max), keras.backend.floatx())
        for c_p, c_t in product(range(nb_cl), range(nb_cl)):
            final_mask += (
                weights[c_t, c_p] * y_pred_max_mat[:, c_p] * y_true[:, c_t])
        return super().call(y_true, y_pred) * final_mask
```

Comment: This looks interesting. What would the input square weights matrix consist of? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a one-liner using scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
class_weights = dict(zip(np.unique(y_train), class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_train), 
                y_train)))
```

Answer (score 4):

If `tf dataset` is used you cannot use the `class_weights` parameter. Insted return the weight from a parse_function in your pipeline

```
weight_arr = [1.5, 0.5] #define your custom weights
    
#create a lookup table
key_tensor = tf.constant(list(range(0, len(weight_arr))), dtype=tf.int64)
val_tensor = tf.constant(weight_arr)
init = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(key_tensor, val_tensor)
weight_table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(init,default_value=-1)

def parse_function(element):
    features = element{'image'}
    label_integer = element{'label'}

    weight = weight_table.lookup(label_integer) #find the weight based on label

    return features, label_integer, weight

ds = ds.map(parse_function)
model.fit(ds)...
```

First you create a lookup table, which maps the given label integer to class weight. Then you fetch the weight based on your label in the pipeline.

Comment: may I ask why I can't use the class weight when tf data is used?

Comment: If a remember it correctly I read is somewhere in the documentation. It may not do any harm, thought it won't work since keras do not know how to add weights to your custom tf data

Comment: I tried using class weights with tf data and it gave me weird errors. The shape of my label is [batch_size, seq_len], where each label is between [0, 3], and the shape of the y_pred is [batch_size, seq_len, 4]. Keras complains an invalid arugment error saying index 18 is not in the range of [0, 3]. I don't even know where the 18 comes from. Labels are double-checked to make sure they are all in the range of [0, 3]. I guess I may have to flatten the y_pred to 2-D array and label to 1-D array to use the class weight feature.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following example of coding up class weights in the loss function using the minist dataset. See link [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115).

```
def w_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, weights):
    nb_cl = len(weights)
    final_mask = K.zeros_like(y_pred[:, 0])
    y_pred_max = K.max(y_pred, axis=1)
    y_pred_max = K.reshape(y_pred_max, (K.shape(y_pred)[0], 1))
    y_pred_max_mat = K.equal(y_pred, y_pred_max)
    for c_p, c_t in product(range(nb_cl), range(nb_cl)):
        final_mask += (weights[c_t, c_p] * y_pred_max_mat[:, c_p] * y_true[:, c_t])
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true) * final_mask
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
itemCt = Counter(trainGen.classes)
maxCt = float(max(itemCt.values()))
cw = {clsID : maxCt/numImg for clsID, numImg in itemCt.items()}
```

This works with a generator or standard. Your largest class will have a weight of 1 while the others will have values greater than 1 depending on how infrequent they are relative to the largest class.

Class weights accepts a dictionary type input.

Answer (score 0):

Dataset [flower_photos.tgz](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz)

| label | count |
| --- | --- |
| daisy | 633 |
| dandelion | 898 |
| roses | 641 |
| sunflowers | 699 |
| tulips | 799 |

Count the number of images in different categories

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

directory = 'flower_photos'
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
data = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory)
unique = np.unique(data.classes, return_counts=True)
labels_dict = dict(zip(unique[0], unique[1]))
print(labels_dict)
# Found 3670 images belonging to 5 classes.
# {0: 633, 1: 898, 2: 641, 3: 699, 4: 799}
```

Calculate the weights of different categories

```py
import math


def get_class_weight(labels_dict):
    """Calculate the weights of different categories

    >>> get_class_weight({0: 633, 1: 898, 2: 641, 3: 699, 4: 799})
    {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0}
    >>> get_class_weight({0: 5, 1: 78, 2: 2814, 3: 7914})
    {0: 7.366950709511269, 1: 4.619679795255778, 2: 1.034026384271035, 3: 1.0}
    """
    total = sum(labels_dict.values())
    max_num = max(labels_dict.values())
    mu = 1.0 / (total / max_num)
    class_weight = dict()
    for key, value in labels_dict.items():
        score = math.log(mu * total / float(value))
        class_weight[key] = score if score > 1.0 else 1.0
    return class_weight


labels_dict = {0: 633, 1: 898, 2: 641, 3: 699, 4: 799}
print(get_class_weight(labels_dict))
# {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0}
labels_dict = {0: 5, 1: 78, 2: 2814, 3: 7914}
print(get_class_weight(labels_dict))
# {0: 1.0, 1: 3.749820767859636, 2: 1.0, 3: 3.749820767859636, 4: 1.0, 5: 2.5931008483842453, 6: 1.0, 7: 2.5931008483842453}
```

Comment: What if all the weights must sum up to 1, @XerCis?