# Setting class weights for categorical labels in Keras using generator

Tags: keras, class-imbalance

I'm working on with an imbalanced dataset in Keras, and would like to give a higher weight to the samples from my minority class. The `fit()` function has a nice `sample_weight` argument, however because of the size of my data I have to use `fit_generator()`.

`fit_generator()` has a `class_weight` argument, which seems useful for this purpose and is already discussed in [Another question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras). However, in this case the labels are not one-hot-encoded/categorical and I could not find whether using `class_weight` also allows for categorical data.

Can use the `class_weight` argument for one-hot-encoded/categorical labels and if so how? Or do I have to resort to a custom weighted loss function?

Answer (score 2):

For categorical data, it is best to use `sample_weight` instead of `class_weight` argument. This can be done by simply giving all samples of a particular class the same weight. `sample_weight` works for categorical data because it takes a numpy array as its value as opposed to a dictionary (which won't work for categorical class labels) in case of `class_weight`.

See: [Keras sequential model methods](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#sequential-model-methods)

> You can either pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as
>   the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the
>   case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape (samples,
>   sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of
>   every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify
>   sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile().

The other way, as you mentioned is using custom weighted loss function. A detailed discussion on it can be found [here.](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2115)

Comment: Using `sample_weight` would indeed be a nice solution, having the `fit_generator` function unfortunately does not provide this option.

Comment: For large data size, you can use `train_on_batch` which has `sample_weight`, instead of `fit_generator`.
Refer this [link](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-use-keras-with-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory) from Keras for further details.