# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'dict_values'

Tags: python

I'm attempting to compute the class_weights for an highly imbalanced set of 9 classes based on the examples discussed in [How to set class weights for imbalanced classes in Keras?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras). Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import math

# labels_dict : {ind_label: count_label}
# mu : parameter to tune 

def create_class_weight(labels_dict,mu=0.15):
    total = np.sum(labels_dict.values())
    keys = labels_dict.keys()
    class_weight = dict()

    for key in keys:
        score = math.log(mu*total/float(labels_dict[key]))
        class_weight[key] = score if score > 1.0 else 1.0

    return class_weight

# random labels_dict
labels_dict = {0: 3400, 1: 1700, 2: 4700, 3: 6800, 4: 3400, 5: 2300, 6: 8300, 7: 1000, 8:9600}

create_class_weight(labels_dict)
```

I'm getting an error log like this:

```
 File "<ipython-input-34-7a9feda1053b>", line 20, in <module>
    create_class_weight(labels_dict)

  File "<ipython-input-34-7a9feda1053b>", line 11, in create_class_weight
    score = math.log(mu*total/float(labels_dict[key]))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'dict_values'
```

I'm running the code with Python 3.6.3. What modifications am I supposed to make?

Comment: This is more of a StackOverflow question. Nothing related to Data Sciene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use numpy to sum the values of a dictionary. You have to use `sum` function.

```
total = sum(labels_dict.values())
```

Now you can check that `total` is an integer :

```
print(type(total))
```

> class 'int'