# How to set class weights for imbalanced classes in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Do we have an equivalence for the following question, but with tensorflow : [How to set class weights for imbalanced classes in Keras?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras) ??

Comment: Please ask a self-contained question, so we don't have to click on some link to understand what you are asking, and so we don't have to guess what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function that does it automatically: `tf.contrib.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits, onehot_labels, weight=weight)`